# How to make use of lambda.r type checking?

Tags: r, types, functional-programming

I must be using this wrong because, as you can see below, lambda.r's type checking doesn't seem to provide much safety:

```
library(lambda.r)
x <- Integer(5)
> x
[1] 5
attr(,"class")
[1] "Integer" "numeric"
> x %isa% Integer
[1] TRUE
> 6 %isa% Integer
[1] FALSE
> (x + 1) %isa% Integer
[1] TRUE
> (x + .5) %isa% Integer
[1] TRUE
> (x + .5)
[1] 5.5
attr(,"class")
[1] "Integer" "numeric"
>
```

Comment: what is `Integer()`?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me...

```
library(lambda.r)

x <- as.integer(5)
class(x)
# [1] "integer"
x %isa% integer
# [1] TRUE
6 %isa% integer
# [1] FALSE
6L %isa% integer
# [1] TRUE
class(5.5)
# [1] "numeric"
(x + .5) %isa% integer
# [1] FALSE
```